# starting activity from a callback method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, callback, intentservice

i use a class    WebServiceAdapter   using volley library for implementing http connections. since i can't find a way to return a string to activity
 i use an interface to callnback into MainActivity. in it i want to start a new activity but it is not starting

my WebServiceAdapterClass

```
public WebServiceAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    status = "new";
    rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}

private WebServiceInterface wsi;
public void sendGetRequest(String page,Map<String,String> map, WebServiceInterface i){
    wsi = i;
    String query = "";
    if(!map.isEmpty()){
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
         query =query + entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue()+'&';
    }
    }
    if(query.length() != 0)
        query = query.substring(0,query.length()-1);
    StringRequest sRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,BASE_URI+page+"?"+query,
            new Response.Listener<String>()  {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response){
                    wsi.successCallback(response,context);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    wsi.errorCallback("failed",context);

                }

            });
    rQueue.add(sRequest);
}
```

and in MainActivity inside callBack which use an interface for callback

```
@Override
public void successCallback(String s, Context c) {
    Intent myintent = new Intent(c,VerifyRegister.class);
    startActivity(myintent);
    finish();

}
```

but the activity is not starting 
i tried passing this , getApplicationContext() and Main Activity.this instead of c. but never worked

what i wanted was return a string on success i cant find another way
but the new activity is not starting

**update**

code of verifyRegister class

```
public class VerifyRegister extends Activity implements WebServiceInterface{

 private Button verifyButton;
 private EditText loginVerify;
 StorageAdapter sAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sAdapter = new StorageAdapter();
    if(sAdapter.getValue(this, "phone").length() == 0)
        finish();
    setContentView(R.layout.login_verify);
     verifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verifyButton);
     loginVerify = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginVerify);

     verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){

             }
     });

}

@Override
public void successCallback(String s, Context c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void errorCallback(String s, Context c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

***update 2 ***
i called the WebService Adapter like this

```
wAdaptor = new WebServiceAdapter(this);
        wAdaptor.sendGetRequest("/register",new  HashMap<String,String>      (),this);
```

Comment: Is successCallback() method is inside an activity? And Did you try to debug any check it is actually going to the  successCallback() method

Comment: check successCallBack is getting called or not.Second thing try to use start another Activity from mainActivity by StartActivityOnResult and after finshing job of new Activity ..receives the result in onActivityResult in MainActivity...

Comment: @Soham yes it is inside activity and i already verified it is getting called but activity is not starting.

Comment: @Anshuman i am new in android. i cant understand what you are saying. and i verified callback is  getting called

Comment: Are you getting any error message in stacktrace

Comment: @Soham no errors. 
all i want is return a string from webservice adapter class how can i do that it will be enough for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i searched similar projects in github
and found this

```
public void successCallback(String s, Context c) {
Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,VerifyRegister.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myintent);
finish()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that your **VerifyRegister** class does in fact extends **Activity**. And if it does extends, please make sure that you have added it in **AndroidManifest** file.
One more thing you can try is, you can write it like this:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,VerifyRegister.class);
```

Comment: it extends activity and i tried MainActivity.this  no error just not starting new activity.

Comment: And it also exists in AndroidManifest?

Comment: all i want is to return a string from WebServiceAdapter is  there another way to do this without using callbacks

Comment: Can you please share your code from VerifyRegister class?

Comment: i edited the question to include VerifyRegister class

Comment: Please comment out the finish(); function inside VerifyRegister class and let me know If it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void successCallback(String s, Context c) {
    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,VerifyRegister.class);
    c.startActivity(myintent);
    //finish(); Dont use this

}
```

Comment: not working . all i want to do is return a string is there a way to return a string from webserviceadapter

Comment: let suppose if you want to start a new activity B from existing activity A.and After finishing Activity B ,you want to send some result back to activity A. you need to use startActivityForResult to launch activity B from A. you also need to override the function protected void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) in activity A to recive the result from Activity B

Comment: @Anushman i dont want to do so. all i want is "how to get string returned from a Volley class" somebody sugested callbacks and i did so. but activity is not starting

Comment: @haseeb .. You can use intent for this. Broadcast an intent with information you want to pass and receives into your broadcast..

Answer (score 0):

New activity starts with Context, I your case you should call it by using to activity currently running.

`MainActivity.this.startActivity(anyintent);`